# ToC, LoF, LoT with same style as chapter style

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, incompatibility, tocloft, fncychap

I've added ToC, LoF and LoT in a `.tex` file in which the chapter style is Glenn.
The problem is that ToC, LoF and LoT don't adapt the desired style, while bibliography i.e. does. I've tried

```
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```

but it didn't work. The code I am using is

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfiles}

%\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\definecolor{Darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.4}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhf{} % delete current setting for header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line}

\parskip 3mm
\footskip = 15mm
%```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

%```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
\begin{document}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Front-Page~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{titlepage}
TitlePage
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\textcolor{Darkblue}{\tableofcontents}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}
\listoffigures
%\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}
\listoftables
%\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\newpage

\subfile{abstractGR.tex}

\end{document}
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

The subfile is just a test file...

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{Darkblue}{\chapter{Intro}}
    This is just a test subfile
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loading `tocloft` with the `titles` option (see p.7 of the manual for details) is a good start. As there also seems to be an incompatibility between the `\tableofcontents` definition of the standard classes and `fncychap`, I use an unnumbered `\contentsname` chapter plus a "bare" ToC.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tocwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{\contentsname}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
\tocwithouttitle

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A fake bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is working!!!
However, my compiler didn't understund the option "title" so I just removed and it works fine, apart from some errors in .toc. The important thing is that this is working like a charm in ToC, LoF and LoT as well!

Thank you very much!